# .htaccess remove specific get parameter from url

Tags: .htaccess

Hello I have been searching the web for an answer to this but I can not find it. I am looking to use htaccess to strip a specific parameter from the url.

For example, I have the following urls:

```
www.mysite.com/product.php?product_id=123&session=sdfs98d7fs9f8d7
www.mysite.com/anotherurl.php?session=12312341341&someotherparam=123
```

I would need them to 301 redirect to:

```
www.mysite.com/product.php?product_id=123
www.mysite.com/anotherurl.php?someotherparam=123
```

Note the urls above are just examples.  Ill need the session param removed from any and all urls no matter how many params are part of the url or where session is located.

I think I need a way to the url string up to session=blah and the url string after session=blah, then combine both parts and redirect to the new url.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on [another site](http://forums.westhost.com/showthread.php?8010-Use-htaccess-to-Strip-Session-ID-from-Bots)

```
# case: leading and trailing parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)&session=[0-9a-z]+&(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1&%2 [R=301,L]

# case: leading-only, trailing-only or no additional parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)&session=[0-9a-z]+$|^osCsid=[0-9a-z]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

In short, what you want is just to remove the key-value pair `session=xx` from the query.

Here is an option:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*)?&?session=[^&]+&?(.*)?  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)
RewriteRule .*  %3?%1%2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah the urls would be dynamic the two I had were just examples I just need the session param removed from any and all urls

Comment: Thanks faa.  It doesn't look like your updated answer would work if the other parameter is not product_id or had more than one valid parameter.  I think I'm looking for something that would take any url before session=blah and any url after session=blah and then redirect to the combined parts.

Comment: @bones Updated my answer again.

Comment: Thanks faa.  It's not quite working.  When I have the url:  www.mysite.com/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=2894&session=d794705  it redirects to www.mysite.com/products_id=2894  I would need it to redirect to  www.mysite.com/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=2894

Comment: ¿Is the script name also variable or it is now `product_info.php` instead of `product.php` ?

Comment: the url can be anything, the only common would be that they have the parameter session in them.

Comment: @bones This is being assembled by daily pieces. But it's okay, I updated my answer again. Hope this time works.

Comment: Almost!  I switched your last line around to `RewriteRule .*  %3%1?%2? [R=301,L]` (notice the ? was between %3 and %1) and if I have the url: `http://www.mysite.com/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=2894&session=d794705` I get `http://www.mysite.com/catalog/product_info.php?%3f`

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} product_id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule .* product.php?product_id=%1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I should have mentioned the irks could be totally different.  The common denominator being  the session param which I need removed from any URL.  I've adjusted the question